Langlands correspondence of coverings of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and modular forms with fractional weights
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $G \to \SL_2(\mathbb R)$ be a finite covering of degree $d \geq 2$. Then $G$ is a connected Lie group with semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and maximal compact group $K=\{ (g,z) \in U(1) \times U(1) | g=z^d \}$.
Note $G$ is a connected semi-simple Lie group, but not algebraic. The construction of discrete series by Harish-Chandra still makes sense.
Question: could we classify irreducible admissible representations of $G$ (or $(g,K)$-modules) and match them with certain morphism of $W_\mathbb R \to {}^LG$ (a dual group to be defined)? What are character formulas (e.g. for limits of discrete series)?
For $d=2$, this is well-studied (and related to modular forms of half weights). The dual shall be $\SL_2$. The characters for genuine representations are computed, including irreducible parts of Weil representation of $\widetilde{\SL_2}(\mathbb R)$.
For general $d$, $G$ is not a Brylinski-Deligne covering group. It shall be related to modular forms of fractional weights. I suspect some computations are done in old literature. Thank you very much for references.
